# Split string to array and order arr[1] ? - MS SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I want to order a value like 1234_1 (id, index) in correct way. Remove 123_ and then just order the index. How can i do it in right way in Microsoft SQL... Cheers

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: In Microsoft SQL.  I know. Bad tags. "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY "123_1" DESC" to "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY 1 DESC" (?)

Comment: There is no "123_" in your example value.  A (text) table of values with desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Substring` and `charindex` :

To order by it :

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(YourColumn, CHARINDEX('_', YourColumn) + 1, LEN(YourColumn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to order by the index *numerically* (so `_10` is after `_9` rather than `_1`).

You can extract the value and convert to a number:

```
order by try_convert(int, stuff(col, 1, charindex('_', col), ''))
```